# Memory usage in docker container - 600MB for OS only?

Tags: docker, top, solr

I am running docker swarm across two Debian 8 nodes, each with 1GB ram.

I wanted to see how much memory was available to my application process (which will be a Solr server) so I did:

```
docker-compose run solr bash
```

In other words, instead of the solr server process I am just running a bash shell, inside a container otherwise identical to the one which will run my server.

If I run `top` this is what I see:

```
top - 16:23:57 up  6:09,  0 users,  load average: 0.00, 0.01, 0.05
Tasks:   2 total,   1 running,   1 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
%Cpu(s):  0.0 us,  0.0 sy,  0.0 ni, 99.3 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.3 si,  0.3 st
KiB Mem:   1024468 total,   634016 used,   390452 free,    93124 buffers
KiB Swap:        0 total,        0 used,        0 free.   375932 cached Mem

  PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND
   11 solr      20   0   23640   2704   2320 R  0.3  0.3   0:00.01 top
    1 solr      20   0   21940   3540   3044 S  0.0  0.3   0:00.12 bash
```

Apparently out of 1GB allocated to the container I am using 634MB, even though the only two processes running in the container are `top` and `bash`.

How much should I expect normally to be consumed by the OS?

I assume some of this is consumed by the Docker daemon and swarm too, outside the container on the host node.

hmm, I've just read this http://www.linuxatemyram.com/ ...should I interpret `top` to mean that, of the 634MB 'used', 375MB of that is just disk cache and is available to my app process?

So I really have 766MB free -  is that right?

The point of all this is so I can start my Solr server process with a realistic memory limit, to make best use of the 1GB node without getting shut down due to out-of-memory error.

**UPDATE**

Ok this has been marked as duplicate, so it is the 'linux ate my ram' thing. From that page the answer is not to use `top` but rather:

```
$ dc run solr bash
solr@59cb7fafca0e:/opt/solr-4.10.4$ free -m
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:          1000        628        371          8         94        372
-/+ buffers/cache:        161        838
Swap:            0          0          0
```

...and from this the 'true' free memory figure is **838MB**
(which seems to derive from `free + buffers + cached`)